# Hide Field on Specific SPListItems

Tags: 2010, splistitem, spfield, hidden

I am trying to figure out if I can hide/show a field for specific list items using the SP object model. I am aware that you can set the [SPField.Hidden property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.hidden.aspx)  however it appears as though this does it for the whole list. Is there a way to set this at the listitem level so that potentially it could be hidden on one item and not another?

Comment: Can you expand on the use case?  It would be helpful to know where in the UI (i.e. list view) you are trying to hide it along with why you are trying to do this.

Comment: See related question... http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79255/hide-field-on-initial-edit-form